# How to solve else / else if problems discord js

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to create "activate system" by this:

```
if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content == 'v/activate secret') {
            message.channel.send('BOT is successfully activated.');
            message.author.send('Uspesno si aktivirao nas servis. Aktivacioni kljuc cuvaj,bice redovnih provera.');
    } else if {
        message.channel.send('***Wrong license key***');
    }
```

But when I type command like this `v/hey` bot send me message  `message.channel.send('***Wrong license key***');`
I don't want to use any handlers and other systems.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this ?

```
if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content == 'v/activate secret') {
            message.channel.send('BOT is successfully activated.');
            message.author.send('Uspesno si aktivirao nas servis. Aktivacioni kljuc cuvaj,bice redovnih provera.');
    } else if(message.content == 'v/hey') {
        message.channel.send('hlooo');
    } else {
       message.channel.send('***Wrong license key***');
    }
```

Comment: No man.
I want just that "system" for activation in one,without else if and then other commands. If you can understand me.